# Recursive make distclean: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, makefile, autoconf, automake

I have the following directories:

```
$ cd dir1
$ tree
[...]
├── autogen.sh
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── common.gmake.in
├── configure.ac
├── Makefile.am
├── src
│   ├── Makefile.am
│   ├── Makefile.in
│   ├── [...]
│   └── dir2
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── Makefile.am 
│       ├── [...]
```

And in the Makefile.am of dir2, I have:

```
[...]
include @abs_top_builddir@/common.gmake
[...]
```

The first time I compile, everything works just fine. But if I want to compile a second time, because I produced a config.status file, the Makefile wants to execute a make distclean. It will execute it in dir1 and will remove the common.gmake. But as it is recursive, when it will enter in the dir2 directory, I have the following error:

```
Making distclean in dir2
gmake[2]: Entering directory `/dir1/src/dir2'
Makefile:1760: /dir1/common.gmake: No such file or directory
gmake[2]: *** No rule to make target `/dir1/common.gmake'.  Stop.
```

It looks like to me the recursive target generated by automake is wrong as it wants to remove a file it already removed previously. What do you think ?

Comment: This is one problem with recursive [auto]make: the toplevel Makefile is what understands how to create, use, and clean `common.gmake`, but a Makefile in a subdirectory requires that file, meaning when the `distclean` target executes in the toplevel Makefile, the Makefile in the subdirectory can't find the file it needs. Switching to a non-recursive build instead, specifying all paths relative to the toplevel source/build directories would solve this issue as there'd only be one `distclean` target. Consult [the Autotools Mythbuster](https://autotools.io/automake/nonrecursive.html) for more info

Comment: Thank you @ChronoKitsune for your answer. I was wondering how is it possible to switch to a non-recursive build instead as I am using a Makefile.am. Can I "redefine" the distclean target in the Makefile.am so automake is not generating its own distclean target ?

Comment: The problem here is that `distclean` in the toplevel directory will remove everything generated by `configure` in the toplevel directory as well. You either need to create a subpackage (i.e. `dir2` has its own `configure` script) or switch to a non-recursive build (again, see the link above for info). [The GNU Automake manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Alternative.html) can also help with both.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. I know I have to switch to a non-recursive build but meanwhile (as it may take some time), I am looking for some king of hack. What do you think about putting a condition on the file: if it exists, we can include it, otherwise, we do not include it ?

Comment: Yes, that is a possibility, so long as it doesn't break anything else. As you have a CMakeLists.txt already in `dir2`, however, you're building a subpackage already if CMake is used to build things, so you could just create a `configure.ac` in that directory that does what you want, including copy the toplevel `common.gmake` to `dir2` and rely on that. This way, you won't have errors with the toplevel `distclean` target. It's the simplest hack I can think of that retains all functionality, assuming you require information from `common.gmake` in your generated `dir2/Makefile`.

Comment: And in your `dir2/Makefile.am`, you could use the `distclean-local:` target with a rule that removes `common.gmake`, so `dir2/configure` can recopy the toplevel `common.gmake` file.

Comment: I didn't understand this: "the Makefile wants to execute a make distclean".  Rebuilding doesn't require a distclean.  It made me wonder if something fishy is going on here.

Comment: @TomTromey: in my script used to build my project, I have the following : "if test -f "dir1/config.status"; then make -C dir1 distclean fi" so the second time I execute the script, it executes the distclean.

Comment: That seems like a strange thing to do, but alright.  Normally I think distclean should proceed in reverse order of the build.  I wonder what your `SUBDIRS` looks like and whether it includes `.`.

Comment: What I do not understand is: in the generated Makefile in dir2, why is my makefile executed ? (it fails on the include but it should not execute this line !)